# tensorboard unable to load graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

[Tensorboard gets stuck here forever (parsing graph.pbxt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHd6n.png)

[However, the scalars are being displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS2Ei.png)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have figured out why it didn't work for me.
The problem was that I used a tensorflow dataset generated by

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, hidden))
```

where the input were numpy arrays.
This basically creates a constant in your graph. The problem was that my data was too large and (I guess) that is why it takes so unbelievably long to load the graph.
If you feed the data into a placeholder it will save the data on disk and fetch only needed data (size of the batch).

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
```

You also need to initialize some things:

```
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: X,
                                          labels_placeholder: y})
```

This resolved my problem.
I hope this helps you or others.